# UTFDataFormatException for umlauts in webservice client

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

I'm sending a request to a soap webservice of a customer.
When sending umlauts, I'm getting an exception back:

`java.io.UTFDataFormatException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.`

Is this an error on my or on their side? What could I change from the client side to prevent this error when sending umlauts in the request?

I'm using `CXF`.

Comment: Show us your code, maybe?

Comment: Sounds like your xml says you're using UTF-8 encoding while in reality you're using something else (e.g. ISO-8859-something). This will be difficult to sort out via this site since you'll have to look at the binary data you are sending - and all encoding issues will get lost when posting to this site :-(

Comment: Maybe it helps that both implementing a CXF client and using soapUI produces this error...